# ¿Cómo eliminar &nbsp que se repite varias veces en un string JS?

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando eliminar `&nbsp` de un string; esto ya lo había logrado con este código:

```js
    const data = 'Darwin &nbsp;';
    const newData = data.replace('&nbsp;', '');
    console.log(newData);
    // Sin embargo me di cuenta de que si el string tiene muchos espacios solo se borra un espacio de la  siguiente manera.
  const data2 = 'Darwin &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp';
  const newData2 = data2.replace('&nbsp;', '');
  console.log(newData2)
```

¿Cómo puedo eliminar todas las veces que se repita `&nbsp;` en mi String?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podrías aplicar alguna de las siguientes opciones, considerando que tienes `'&nbsp;' '&nbsp'`
en el string data2.

Opcion 1.

```js
   const data2 = 'Darwin &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp';
  const newData2 = data2.replaceAll("&nbsp;", '').replaceAll("&nbsp", '').trim();
  console.log(newData2)
```

La siguiente podría utilizarse para hacerlo tanto en mayúsculas como minúsculas por medio de expresión regular global case insensitive.
Opción 2:

```js
    const data2 = 'Darwin &nbsp; &NBSP; &nbsp';
      const regex1 = /&nbsp;/ig;
      const regex2 = /&nbsp/ig;
      const newData2 = data2.replaceAll(regex1, '').replaceAll(regex2, '').trim();
      console.log(newData2)
```

Comment: Gracias por compartirme siempre de tus conocimientos.

Comment: Es un placer poder ayudar.

Answer (score 2):

Con una regex puedes cubrir ambos casos

```
const newData = data2.replace(/&nbsp[;]?/ig, '');
```